# case label not within a switch statement error in linux

Tags: linux, switch-statement, rpc

When I compile an application in Linux 5, Iget the following error.

api_svc1.c:335: error: case label not within a switch statement
api_svc1.c:340: error: âdefaultâ label not within a switch statement

c program 'api_svc1.c' is generated by rpcgen. Switch statement is not found in the geberated code.

The code fragment is given below:

```
result = (*local)((char *)&argument, rqstp);
if (result != NULL && !svc_sendreply(transp, (xdrproc_t) _xdr_result, result)) {
        svcerr_systemerr (transp);
       _exit (-1);
     }
     _exit (0);
   case -1:
    /*
     * Error - fork couldn't create the child process, return
     */
     svcerr_systemerr(transp);
   default:
     /*
      * Parent process, clean up any zombie children and
      * return to svc_run()
      */
      svc_destroy(transp);
      while (waitpid(-1,NULL,WNOHANG) > 0);
      _rpcsvccount--;
      _rpcsvcstate = _SERVED;
      return;
```

The same code was generated and compiled successfully in Solaris without errors.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: As the error states, your case/default are not within a switch() block. Just because one compiler accepts this doesn't mean another one will.

Comment: You need to show the entire function.  At first glance, the compiler appears correct -- `case -1:` and `default:` make no sense without an enclosing `switch`.  This code may be unreachable, but the compiler is still required to reject code which is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: I suspect you must mean that your SunRPC code generated and built fine on Solaris, not that the Solaris `rpcgen` produced the same C code as the `rpcgen` on Linux, but which then compiled on Solaris.

Comment: Hi Kaz, the code generated by solaris rpcgen also did not contain the switch statement. But still it got compiled.

Comment: But this is a compiler generated code. Hence it is not possible to modify the code manually to add a switch case. Any other solution fot this?

Comment: Fix the code generator. The code is wrong.